# Extract the title from a webpage using the python 3 standard lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

The aim of this module is to extract the title from possibly broken hypertext. Without using any awesome third party modules like `bs4` or `lxml`.

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:3
#qpy:console

''' 
Extract the title from a web page using
the standard lib.
'''

from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib

def error_callback(*_, **__):
    pass

def is_string(data):
    return isinstance(data, str)

def is_bytes(data):
    return isinstance(data, bytes)

def to_ascii(data):
    if is_string(data):
        data = data.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
    elif is_bytes(data):
        data = data.decode('ascii', errors='ignore')
    else:
        data = str(data).encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
    return data


class Parser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.title = None
        self.rec = False
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        try:
            self.feed(to_ascii(urlopen(url).read()))
        except urllib.error.HTTPError:
            return
        except urllib.error.URLError:
            return
        except ValueError:
            return

        self.rec = False
        self.error = error_callback

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'title':
            self.rec = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.rec:
            self.title = data

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'title':
            self.rec = False


def get_title(url):
    return Parser(url).title

print(get_title('http://www.google.com'))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `error_callback`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger  `error_callback()`  is used to overwrite `HTMLParser`'s error method.

Answer (score 5):

Looks pretty clean to me, good job! Here's what I recommend:

- The `to_ascii` function is small and readable, but in my opinion the `is_string` and `is_bytes` functions are overkill:

  ```
  def to_ascii(data):
      if isinstance(data, str):
          ...
      elif isinstance(data, bytes):
          ...
      else:
          ...
  ```
- We can make `to_ascii` less complex by returning immediately:

  ```
  def to_ascii(data):
      if isinstance(data, str):
          return data.encode("ascii", errors="ignore")
      elif isinstance(data, bytes):
          return data.decode("ascii", errors="ignore")
  ```

  We can then leave out the `else` clause:

  ```
  def to_ascii(data):
      if isinstance(data, str):
          return data.encode("ascii", errors="ignore")
      elif isinstance(data, bytes):
          return data.decode("ascii", errors="ignore")
      return str(data).encode("ascii", errors="ignore")
  ```
- `error_callback` is pretty much useless. Maybe you planned on adding more functionality to the `Parser` class, but as is, you can just leave it out.
- I don't expect a parser's constructor to automatically parse the data I pass. How about:

  ```
  class Parser(HTMLParser):
      def __init__(self, data):
          self._data = data
          ...

      def parse(self):
          self._parsed = self.feed( ... )
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Your `Parser` class both define the rules of the parser you’re building **and** process the data on its own. This is too much, you should only define the parser in this class and handle data retrieval (URL reading) in an other function.

That being said, keep the habit of using [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) instead of calling the base class method directly this will help you when you’ll get into trickier inheritance schemes.

---

Your `to_ascii` function is harmful, as the [`feed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.feed) method of the `HTMLParser` explicitly expects an `str`. Your `to_ascii` returns an `str` if `data` is of `bytes` type and a `bytes` otherwise. Don't.

Instead, you could either extend the `feed` behaviour to allow for any type in your subclass; or explicitly convert the result of `urlopen(..).read()` that you know to be of `bytes` type.

And speaking of `urlopen(..).read()` you should use the result of the [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) call as the contextmanager it is supposed to be to ease resources management.

---

Your error handling seems off, as you don't do anything on errors. I, personally would be happier to see why a request failed with a whole traceback rather than getting a title that is `None` (*i.e.* I’m loosing information here). Besides, `HTTPError` being a subclass of `URLError`, you don't need both in your excepts.

---

Lastly, use an [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard so you can more easily import your script for testing purposes.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-

#qpy:3
#qpy:console

''' 
Extract the title from a web page using
the standard lib.
'''

from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError


class Parser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = ''
        self._in_title_tag = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'title':
            self._in_title_tag = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self._in_title_tag:
            self.title += data

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'title':
            self._in_title_tag = False


def get_title(url):
    try:
        with urlopen(url) as stream:
            data = stream.read()
    except URLError:
        return

    parser = Parser()
    parser.feed(data.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore'))
    return parser.title


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_title('http://www.google.com'))
```

Comment: `to_ascii()` will always return a ASCII encoded `str`

Comment: @RickyWilson Sure… `>>> to_ascii('test')
b'test'`

Comment: how can this be fixed